# How to Use ASP.NET MVC to get "content = page source" from another web page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

How to Use ASP.NET MVC to get "content = page source" from another web page?

Comment: What do you mean by get content? Do you want to load the entire source of another page into a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "get content", but here's a function for downloading html-source from any website:

```
public string Download(string url, Encoding encoding)
{
    string content = string.Empty;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient { Encoding=encoding })
    {
        Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data, encoding))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        data.Close();
    }
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
```